# How can i apply the css style of the URL and Quote tag in the xsl file?

Tags: css, xml, xslt

```
<news><story><p>Located online at <url>www.guessthatgroove.com</url>, the service is
  entirely free. He explained that the business model is based upon
  commission fees from linked sites such as Amazon.com and iTunes, which
  offer game players an option to purchase CDs and individual music tracks
  that they encounter throughout the game. It's too early to tell whether
  he has hit on another social phenomonon along the lines of Tall
  Tales. Regarding the potential success of the online game, he
  replied, <quote>It was a lot of fun to create and I enjoy playing it
  myself, so in some ways I already consider it a success</quote>.</p>
```

xsl:

```
#p
{
width:450px;
text-align:left;
margin-bottom:8px;
color:black;
font-family:Verdana, Arial;
font-size:10pt
}
url
{
font-weight:bold
}
quote
{
font-style:italic
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="p">
        <xsl:value-of select="news/story/p" />
    </div>
```

My question is How can i apply the css style of the URL and Quote tag in the xsl file?

Comment: Assuming your XSL is outputing HTML (which is what it looks like), I would expect the CSS to get applied to any `div` tag with the id of `p`, just like it says.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of <xsl:value-of select="news/story/p" /> use <xsl:apply-templates/> and create templates for URL and Quote.